# Emacs font with antialiasing and hinting

Tags: emacs, fonts, antialiasing

I'm using Fedora 17 and Emacs 24 and wanted to try liberation fonts on Emacs.  I've tried this with `HOME/.Xresources`:

```
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.lcdfilter:  lcddefault
Xft.rgba:   rgb
Emacs.font: Liberation Mono-12
```

That changes only normal text, but not other text such as `ORG-MODE` headings. I don't know if antialiasing is working either.

I've also tried:

```
(set-fontset-font
nil '(#x0250 . #x02af) (font-spec :family "Liberation Mono"))
```

but it's still the same.

Comment: I'll change one by one as you said. I couldn't find a way to globally change a mode's font. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to say that anti-aliasing seems to work using your settings above.. thanks - still useful after all these years!

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that the `org-mode` faces are set to inherit correctly from the `default` face.

Answer (score 1):

I put the following bit of code in my `.emacs.d` to change the default font:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Ubuntu Mono" :height 120 :weight 'normal)
```

Whether the font is being anti-aliased and hinted is dependent on the program drawing the emacs window. So if you're running the X Windows version of Emacs inside Gnome or KDE, then Gnome/KDE will draw the fonts as hinted and anti-aliased. If you're running emacs inside a terminal, then you need to research how to use anti-aliased and hinted fonts inside the terminal (which if you're using a terminal emulator inside of a window manager is still tied to the abilities of the window manager itself).